# Can't see "Assigned Access" options in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I need to use the new "Assigned Access" options in Windows 8.1 to lock a tablet down to only use a single app.

I attempted to follow this guide:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx

But I do not appear to have the "Set up and account for assigned access" link on the Accounts screen.

Does anyone know why this option is missing for me?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This seems to suggest that it work on windows 8 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/assigned-access

Comment: The accepted answer was correct, it depends on the version you have. I had Standard Edition, so no feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This feature is not available in all Windows 8.1 editions](http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/). You need the Pro, Enterprise or the RT Edition:

> Assigned Access is available on Windows 8.1 RT, Windows 8.1 Professional, and Windows 8.1 Enterprise. The **standard edition** of Windows 8.1 doesn’t support Assigned Access.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late, but I just purchased a device that uses windows 8.1 with Bing and used the following article which worked for me

Configuring Kiosk Mode on Your Windows XP Computer

To configure the computer to automatically log into a specific user account, you will need to modify the Windows Registry. Do this carefully by following these steps:
1.Click Start»Run.
2.Type the command regedit. Click OK.
3.Browse to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE»Software»Microsoft»Windows NT»CurrentVersion»Winlogon.
4.Double-click the DefaultUserName entry and enter in the name of the user account that you want to automatically log into. Click OK.

5.Double-click the DefaultPassword entry and enter in the password for the user account that you want to log into. Click OK

If there is not a DefaultPassword entry, create the value using the following steps:
1.Go to Edit»New»String Value.
2.Name the new value DefaultPassword and press Enter.
3.Double-click the newly created entry and enter in the password for the user account that you want to log into. Click OK.

NOTE: If no DefaultPassword string is specified, Windows XP automatically changes the value of the AutoAdminLogon registry key from 1 (true) to 0 (false) to turn off the AutoAdminLogon feature.

6.Double click the AutoAdminLogon entry and enter in 1 for its Value Data. Click OK.

If there is not an AutoAdminLogon entry, create the value using the following steps:
1.Go to Edit»New»String Value.
2.Name the new value AutoAdminLogon and press Enter.
3.Double-click the newly created entry and enter in 1 for its Value Data. Click OK.

7.Close the Registry Editor by going to File»Exit or by clicking the red X in the top right corner of the window.
8.Restart the computer by going to Start»Shutdown and then select Restart.

To configure a specific account to boot into Kiosk Mode, you will need to modify the Windows Registry. Do this carefully by following these steps:
1.Log into the user account that you wish to boot into Kiosk Mode.
2.Click Start»Run.
3.Type the command regedit. Click OK.
4.Browse to HKEY_CURRENT_USER»Software»Microsoft»Windows NT»CurrentVersion»Winlogon.
5.Add a new string value to this registry by going to Edit»New»String Value and name it Shell.
6.Double-click on this new string value and enter in the path to the executable you want to run instead of explorer.exe (e.g. C:\LV Startup\MyLabVIEWVI.exe).
7.Log out of the user account and log back in.
By combining these two configurations, you can set up your Windows XP machine to automatically bypass the user logon screen and boot into a specific user account that will run any LabVIEW executable you build instead of Windows Explorer (explorer.exe). You may want to customize the appearance of the executable by modifying its VI Properties. For example, you can have the executable maximize to fill the entire screen by changing the Position option is set to Maximized in the Window Run-Time Position category. You can also customize the Windows Appearance category so that user cannot close or resize the executable.

TIP: If you want to change the executable that is being run for a specific account, but are having trouble getting back to the Registry Editor because there is no longer a Start Menu, you can press Ctrl-Alt-Delete and select to run the Task Manager (if it not already running). Then select File»New Task (Run...) and type regedit in the box that pops up and click OK. This will run the Registry Editor.

Comment: Hi Pete, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)